# Is it possible to detect 'dead' completers in Dart?

Tags: dart

In the Dart vm the following code will not hang - the VM will exit:

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<Null> main() async {
    await neverCompletes();
    print('Will not run');
}

Future<Null> neverCompletes() => new Completer<Null>().future;
```

Is there any way to detect this situation? It would be easier to investigate if the VM hangs waiting for the Future. Any flags I can pass?

Comment: The Observatory allows to investigate the event queue AFAIK, if it's only for debugging purposes.

Comment: That might work if we could catch it in the act. Since the VM quits rather than hangs we might have to step through everything to track it down in a debugger.

Comment: Existing features request: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/23797